# How to set ncdu to enter mounted folders?

Tags: mount

I'm looking on its help and doesn't find a setting for that.

In example, I run it on /mnt. It says all umounted folders are 4KB and all mounted folders are 20KB. I'd like it to enter mounted folders and count their actual size. That regardless if they are ext4, ntfs, cifs, etc.

Comment: Try `ncdu /mnt/*`

Comment: cool it worked tnx :D